# PHP-FPM + Apache (403 forbidden message)

Tags: apache-2.2, php, php-fpm, httpd, fastcgi

Im having trouble installing php-fpm.

When ever I install it and open a php file i get a 403 forbiden status code

Looking at the logs is see

```
client denied by server configuration: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi
```

I changed my  directive to allow from all and the issue fixed itself.

Is there a way to allow access to the cgi-bin without having to allow all to access /?

So far I've tried Allow from 127.0.0.1
Ive also tried adding a directive for the cgi bin.

Neither work

Directives

```
<Directory />
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from All
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory "/srv/public_html">
    Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

FastCGI config

```
AddHandler php5-fcgi .php
Action php5-fcgi /php5-fcgi
Alias /php5-fcgi /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi
FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi -socket /tmp/php5-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization
```

Thanks in advance for any help